# How do I write a file in iOS using FileManager?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I have the following code with the results of the print statements in comments beside the statements:

```
    let myImageData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: myURL.absoluteString)

    var mySaveToURL: URL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)!
    mySaveToURL.appendPathComponent(myURL.pathComponents.last!)

    print("mySaveToURL=", mySaveToURL) // mySaveToURL= file:///Users/shinehah/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/693D4940-1B91-43E1-B5AD-88E9763046C7/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~us~gnolaum~TrialNotifications/ABF236AE-A6E7-403E-ADC4-5BAA5DC734B3.jpeg


    let resultCreateFile = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: mySaveToURL.absoluteString, contents: myImageData, attributes: nil)

    print("resultCreateFile=", resultCreateFile) // resultCreateFile= false


    do {

        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: myURL, to: mySaveToURL)

        print("copy success!") // copy success!

    } catch {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

As you can see I am not able to successfully execute the createFile() method of FileManager but was able to successfully execute the copyItem() method to the same URL.

What do I check to be able to figure out how to get the createFile() method to work?

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are using the wrong API. To get the path of a file system URL you have to use `path`.

```
let resultCreateFile = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: mySaveToURL.path, contents: myImageData, attributes: nil)
```

However there is no reason to create the file explicitly. Just copy the other file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.

I was using that code to test how to code for backward compatibility for iOS 10, where I get a UIImage from a UIImagePickerController instead of a URL.

Thanks again.